# Making an efficient merge function for the game 2048 in python

Tags: python, list, merge, array-merge

I know there a bunch of other posts regarding this topic however I'm taking a slightly different approach.

```
def merge(line):
    """
    Function that merges a single row or column in 2048.
    """
    #remove all non zeros
    no_zeros = [ num for num in line if num != 0 ] 

    #make a pair of all adjacent numbers 
    pairs = zip(no_zeros[:-1] , no_zeros[1:])
    #create a boolean value for each pair depending whether elements are equal  
    is_pair = map( lambda (x,y): x == y , pairs ) 

    merged = []
    count = 0
    last = False #if elements in the last pair are euqal this is true 
    #merging algo 
    for i,pair in enumerate(is_pair):
        if last == False and pair == True :
            merged.append(pairs[i][0]*2)
            last = True #As this is a valid pair the next pair will not need to be 
                        #checked as the first number is the last number from this pair
        # The following two statements allows the pair to be checked it's
        # numbers have not been checked in any previous pair 
        if last == True: 
            count += 1
        if count == 2:
            last = False
            count = 0 

    return merged

print merge([2, 0, 2, 4, 0])
print 'should return [4, 4, 0, 0]'
print '-------------------------------'
print merge([0, 0, 2, 2])
print 'should return [4, 0, 0, 0]'
print '-------------------------------'
print merge([2, 2, 0, 0])
print 'should return [4, 0, 0, 0]'
print 'to merge [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]'
print '-------------------------------'
print merge([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
print 'should return [4, 4, 2, 0, 0]'
print '-------------------------------'
print merge([8, 16, 16, 8])
print 'should return [8, 32, 8, 0]'
```

So far my code merges all pairs. However if a number is not does not have a pair this needs to also be amended to the 'merged list'. I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this in a simplistic way, other that giving every number a unique stamp then if that stamp hasn't been merged it's added to 'merged'. I tried to implement this and it got very convoluted.

Any help would be appreciated

Any suggestions would

EDIT

I have solved my problem with 2 additional statements :

```
# This allows 'un-paired' numbers to be added to 'merged' 
if not last and not pair: 
    merged.append(pairs[i][0])
# The above doesn't take into account the last digit, if 'pairs' has len=1 which is solved by:
if i == len(is_pair)-1 and i>1 and (last or not pair) :
    merged.append(pairs[i][1])
```

Comment: Note that statements like `last == False and pair == True` should be replaced by `not last and pair`, just so that you don't hurt the eyes of other programmers :)

Comment: My general answer to your question would be: if your approach is too convoluted, maybe change your approach. There's (almost?) always a way to make (any?) approach work, but there's not necessarily an elegant solution for every approach.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, it seems to me that if both `last` and `pair` are `False`, you can add the first element of the current pair. For that you'd need to loop over `pairs` (rather than `is_pair`) and then check if the current pair actually is a pair. Something like:

```
for pair in pairs:
    if not last_is_pair:
        is_pair = pair[0] == pair[1]
        if is_pair:
            merged.append(pair[0]*2)
        else:
            merged.append(pair[0])
        last_is_pair = is_pair
```